# How can I post text only to my Facebook wall in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-android-sdk

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
//params.putString("message", "I want to post this text only.");
params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
params.putString("description", "Description");
params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
```

However, I can't post message only, because the bundle must include "link".

Answer (score 0):

> because the bundle must include "link".

This statement is **incorrect**. In the params, just include the `message` property that's it! Don't provide link/picture/caption/description etc. since all these are related to the link only. So, just use the `message` param and it be be posted as the text only.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public class ShareOnFacebook extends Activity{

    private static final String APP_ID = "123456789";
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

    private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
        private static final String EXPIRES = "2040";
        private static final String KEY = "gfdfdfdfdfd";

    private Facebook facebook;
    private String messageToPost;

     public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
             Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            return editor.commit();
          }

          public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
              SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
             facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
             return facebook.isSessionValid();
         }

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
          restoreCredentials(facebook);

          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

         setContentView(R.layout.facebook_dialog);

          facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
          restoreCredentials(facebook);


          String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
         if (facebookMessage == null){
            facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
         }
         messageToPost = facebookMessage;
      }

      public void doNotShare(View button){
          finish();
     }


     public void share(View button){
         if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
             loginAndPostToWall();
         }
         else {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
            /*Intent backhome = new Intent(ShareOnFacebook.this,Quotes_Tab.class);
            startActivity(backhome);*/
        }
     }

       public void loginAndPostToWall(){
            facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }

      public void postToWall(String message){
             Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", message);
         //       parameters.putString("link", "http://theaterbalcony.com/tag/torpedo-3d-malayalam-cartoon/");

                try {
                    facebook.request("me");
             String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false"))    {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            }
             else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }                

    }

     class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
           saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null){
           postToWall(messageToPost);
       }
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
              showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
             finish();
          }
      public void onCancel() {
          showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
          finish();
        }
   }

    private void showToast(String message){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onDestroy();
       finish();
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(final int pKeyCode, final KeyEvent pEvent) {
        // if menu button is pressed
       if (pKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU
               && pEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

           Intent home = new Intent(ShareOnFacebook.this, Quotes_Tab.class);
           finish();
           startActivity(home);
        } else if (pKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && pEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


           Intent home = new Intent(ShareOnFacebook.this,Quotes_Tab.class);
           finish();
           startActivity(home);
           return super.onKeyDown(pKeyCode, pEvent);
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(pKeyCode, pEvent);
    }
      @Override
      protected void onStop() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onStop();
        finish();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the Bundle as motioned by user1632209

```
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

        params.putString("message", msg);
        params.putString("description", "test test test");
```